# Change Company Field Label to something else

Tags: magento2

Using Magento 2.3 Community

At checkout when adding a new address, I need to rename the Company Field Label to something else, how can I achieve that? Also this field appears under my account, edit shipping address. How can I change that label as well?  I dont care how it is stored in the database, I just want the label to change.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to do :

Step 1 : login to admin dashbroad

Step 2 : go to Stores-> Attributes-> Customer Address.

Step 3 : you will see all fields in the forms there. Click on the field you want to change, you will be editing page then you can change the label to what you want.

Cheers.

Comment: Hmm does not exist on my admin
https://www.screencast.com/t/Z9GuHCHX

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick and easy solution, you can do it via Theme Translation, this will change the text per your store locale.

For your currently active theme:

1. Create file:

> app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME_NAME\i18n\en_US.csv

***(change filename based on your locale, en_US is default)***

Example:

```
"Company","Something else"
```

**Note**: this will also change the label in the customer account area when creating a new address from there.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html